# Getting 2 endpoint other than expected one in WCF?

Tags: wcf

I have a service where I am supposed to get only one end point at client when adding my service reference why is that so?

what i have done to configure my service is given below.

```
   try
        {
            Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/Easicreate/SearchService");
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            this.host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SearchServiceContract));
            this.host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISearchServiceContract), binding, "http://localhost:8080/Easicreate/SearchService");
            //// Enable metadata publishing.
            ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            smb.HttpGetUrl = baseAddress;
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
            this.host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
            this.host.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.host = null;
        }
```

I am little bit confused ?

Comment: Can you post the client configuration generated? I'm interested to see what's other endpoint generated. Coming to troubleshooting the issue, I'd check WSDL (to check if service indeed exposes 2 endpoint) and then capture WCF traces at verbose level and check Construct host activity to know from where other endpoint is taken. HTH, Amit

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but try removing

```
smb.HttpGetUrl = baseAddress;
```

and check as you are passing same baseAddress in endpoint and in behaviour, either dont pass url in endpoint

Comment: Nopes yaar i got it by removing all these and by adding these configurations by app.config